# eclipse error :"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.AllRegister()V"

Tags: java, eclipse, centos7, gdal

While using gdal jar in eclipse on centos i get the error as

`"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.AllRegister()V"`

although I have added gdal-2.1.0 jar in my eclipse project

```
static {
                    System.out.println("GDAL init...");
                    gdal.AllRegister();
                    int count = gdal.GetDriverCount();
                    System.out.println(count + " available Drivers");
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            try {
                                    Driver driver = gdal.GetDriver(i);
                                    System.out.println(" " + driver.getShortName() + " : "
                                                    + driver.getLongName());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.err.println("Error loading driver " + i);
                            }
                    }
         }
```

Comment: This question is liable to be put **on hold** as you haven't provided much adequate evidence of how this UnsatisfiedLinkError occurred. Poor grammar is also not recommended as this is not a chat room. As a result, urgent action is needed. Can you give an example program or path that you are using and couldn't get working?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood after trying with gdal 2.3.1 and gdal 2.3.0 thoroughly is that there is some problem with the java bindings in gdal 2.3.x jar files and so I moved for python bindings with gdal.